# Plot power of a straight line not a curve

Tags: r

So I am using the following to script:

```
area <- c(1854,2001,2182,2520,4072,1627,1308,1092,854,1223,2231,1288,898,2328,1660,6018,5420,943,1625,1095,1484,929,1178,4072,2413)
weight1 <- c(24281,28474,33725,40707,76124,16263,12190,10153,8631,13690,34408,15375,8806,36245,20506,109489,104014,11308,23262,11778,20650,8771,12356,76124,28346)
weight <- weight1/1000

df <- data.frame(weight = log10(weight), area = log10(area))

fit_line <- predict(lm(area ~ weight, data=df))
fit_power <- predict(nls(area ~ i*weight^z, start=list(i=2,z=0.7), data=df))

plot(df$weight,df$area)
lines(df$weight,fit_line,col="red")
lines(sort(df$weight),sort(fit_power), col="blue")
```

To do a log - log plot. I can plot a straight with `lm()` but when I use `nls()` to do power fit, it plots a curve and not a straight line, see below:

[image]

How do I plot the power fit in the form of a straight line, or how can I derive it from `lm()`. SO that I have the answer in the form of: y = a*x^b

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding what it is you want, but that line _should_ be curved unless nls just happens to estimate z to be equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plot is not a log plot. To do a log plot:

```
plot(log(area)~log(weight), df)
```

Then to fit a line:

```
LM.Log <- lm(log(area)~log(weight), df)
abline(LM.Log, col="red")
```

And to do a curved line through a straight plot more efficiently:

```
Power <- coef(LM.Log)[2]
LM.Normal <- lm(area~I(weight^Power)+0, df)
plot(area~weight, df)
plot(function(x) coef(LM.Normal)*x^Power, 0, 2, add=T, col="blue")
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be instructive...

```
df <- data.frame(weight, area, weightl = log10(weight), areal = log10(area))
df <- df[order(df$weight),]

fit_line <- predict(lm(areal ~ weightl, data=df))
fit_power <- predict(nls(area ~ i*weight^z, start=list(i=2,z=0.7), data=df))

plot(df$weightl, df$areal)
lines(df$weightl, fit_line, col="red")
lines(df$weightl, log10(fit_power), col="blue")

plot(df$weight, df$area)
lines(df$weight, 10^fit_line, col="red")
lines(df$weight, fit_power, col="blue")
```

I guessed, I hope correctly, that you really want a power curve through the raw values and you're taking log10 as a proxy for such.  So, what you need to do is get predicted values of the raw weight / area relations and then log those and put everything on a log graph.  Or get a the linear of the log values and put them both as curves on a raw graph.  Examine both of the plots produced above.